# Any good alternatives of ImageJ (Fiji)?

Tags: image-processing, python, image-segmentation

I worked on some medical image processing research two decades ago and I used ImageJ then. I started to pick up some medical image processing projects again (some registration and segmentation). I checked out Fiji, which seems to be a successor of ImageJ. But the project does not seem to be very active anymore. I wonder if anyone what is a good alternative platform? I am mostly a Python programmer now and am familiar with machine learning backends like PyTorch and Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to recommend [ICY](https://icy.bioimageanalysis.org/) from Institut Pasteur, mostly dedicated to biomedical image analysis, it was active in June 2022, and  [CImg Library - C++ Template Image Processing Toolkit](https://cimg.eu/),  a small and open-source C++ library for image processing,   promoted by dear colleague  David Tschumperlé  ([G'MIC twitter](https://twitter.com/gmic_eu))(lastest version 3.1.4).

Answer (score 3):

If you’re looking for a large collection of image processing functionality geared towards quantification, I will recommend [DIPlib](https://diplib.org/) (I’m an author). It is different from ImageJ in that it doesn’t have a GUI, you need to write code. It is a C++ library that you can also use from within Python. It is useful for any imaging modality and application.

If you rather build an image processing pipeline through a GUI, I will recommend [CellProfiler](https://cellprofiler.org/). This one is aimed specifically at cell microscopy, though I guess you could use it also for other applications.